# change the color of textbox by using linq

Tags: vb.net

I am using the following to check if any of my textbox is empty.

```
Dim empty = Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)().Where(Function(txt) txt.Text.Length = 0)
If empty.Any Then
  MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Please fill following textboxes: {0}",String.Join(",",empty.Select(Function(txt) txt.Name))))
End If
```

I want to change the color of empty textbox(s) to red but i don't know how to do it. please someone help me in doing this.

Comment: @VigneshKumar it contains that class. you may look at the following http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

In short, you can't. [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx) is meant to query/read data, not write it. But you can always extend the `LINQ` library.

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices
```

```
<Extension()>
Public Module Extensions

    <Extension()>
    Public Function ForEach(Of T)(source As IEnumerable(Of T), action As Action(Of T)) As IEnumerable(Of T)
        For Each item In source
            action.Invoke(item)
        Next
        Return source
    End Function

    <Extension()>
    Public Function ForAll(Of T)(source As IEnumerable(Of T), action As Action(Of IEnumerable(Of T))) As IEnumerable(Of T)
        action.Invoke(source)
        Return source
    End Function

End Module
```

**Usage**

```
Me.Controls _
    .OfType(Of TextBox) _
    .ForEach( _
        Sub(box) 
            box.BackColor = SystemColors.Window
        End Sub) _
    .Where(
        Function(box)
            Return box.Text.Length = 0
        End Function) _
    .ForEach(
        Sub(box)
            box.BackColor = Color.Red
        End Sub)
    .ForAll(
        Sub(source)
            If (source.Count() > 0) Then
                MessageBox.Show( _
                    String.Format( _
                        "Please fill following textboxes: {0}", _
                        String.Join(", ", _
                            source.Select(Function(box) box.Name))))
            End If
        End Sub)
```

Comment: @user2299040 Great! I've improved the code, please see my edit.

Comment: You should put a note that LINQ is meant to query/read data, not write it. So with these extensions you are breaking the paradigm, which typically ends up in a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: @Neolisk I totally agree with the first part, but partially with the last. I think it depends on things like where/ how/ who/ - usage/ maintaining/ documenting etc.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it

```
        empty.ToList().ForEach(Function(txt) txt.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Red)
```